# How would I fix error "AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'submit_button'"

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I keep getting an error for checking the text of a button. Error is "AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'submit_button'". I tried to add it elsewhere however still  Code:

````
    def creation(self):
        if self.submit_button['text'] != "Create a file":
            time.sleep(3)
            self.submit_button['text'] = "Create a file"
            self.submit_button['foreground'] = "black"

        self.creation_title = tk.Label(text="File creator:", font=("arial", 25))
        self.name_label = tk.Label(text="Name:")
        self.age_label = tk.Label(text="Age:")
        self.height_label = tk.Label(text="Height:")
        self.citizen_status_label = tk.Label(text="Citizenship Status:")
        self.submit_button = tk.Button(text="Create a file", command=self.creator, height=3, width=20)
        self.back_button = tk.Button(text="close", command=lambda: [self.options(), self.destroyer("creation")],
                                     height=1, width=5)

        self.name_entry = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.age_entry = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.height_entry = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.citizen_status = tk.StringVar()
        self.citizen_status_valid = tk.Radiobutton(text="Valid", variable=self.citizen_status, value="VALID")
        self.citizen_status_invalid = tk.Radiobutton(text="Invalid", variable=self.citizen_status, value="INVALID")

        self.creation_title.place(x=20, y=25)
        self.name_label.place(x=250, y=97.5)
        self.age_label.place(x=262, y=137.5)
        self.height_label.place(x=248, y=177.5)
        self.citizen_status_label.place(x=191, y=217.5)

        self.submit_button.place(x=20, y=150)
        self.back_button.place(x=20, y=250)

        self.name_entry.place(x=300, y=100)
        self.age_entry.place(x=300, y=140)
        self.height_entry.place(x=300, y=180)
        self.citizen_status_valid.place(x=295, y=220)
        self.citizen_status_invalid.place(x=362.5, y=220)

        print("Creation Menu Created")```
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the attribute before you use it. The very first line of code in your function uses `self.submit_button`, but you don't define `self.submit_button` until several lines later.